# How can I Implement an iOS Wallet?

Tags: transactions, wallet, ios

What are my options in terms of APIs/SDKs to use as an iOS developer in order to initiate BitCoin Transactions from an App?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: To whoever down-voted this Question, would you at least mind mentioning Why? Oh yes, I did make my research and I still decided the Question was worthwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with IOS/Android (Mobile technology), go for ionic cordova application with BitcoinJS. It will help you to create, sign & send transaction over network.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately a hybrid App is not an option at the moment. Are you saying there isn't a BitCoin iOS native library that exists at the moment?

Comment: (https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-ios-sdk) you can use this library but it is deprecated for now and development is going on, I will suggest integrate bitcoin core library which is written in c++. It would help you to develop native iOS native library.

Comment: Thanks, I think I wouldn't use it anyways, because it's CoinBase, I'm not sure how much of a bad idea is to be tied to them while I try to create a new Brand on top of it, y'know...

Comment: Ok if you are satisfied with the answer, upvote it so it will get clossed